# The shortest way to create a array in descending order in Swift

Tags: arrays, swift, initialization

I can create an array in ascending order in Swift in the following way

```
let x = Array(100...999)
```

However if I do the opposite, e.g something like

```
let x = Array(999...100) //Does not work
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

How about this?

```
let x = Array((100...999).reverse())
```

P.S. The [`Stridable` protocol](http://swiftdoc.org/v2.2/protocol/Strideable/) is handy for when you arithmetic progressions other than just `+1`.

Here's an example of using it here: (Swift 2.2)

```
let x = Array(999.stride(through: 100, by: -1))
```

And in Swift 3.0:

```
let x = Array(stride(from: 999, through: 100, by: -1))
```

Comment: Understandable.  `to` seems intuitive.  Perhaps they should have used `toward` and `to` instead of `to` and `through`.

Comment: "upTo:" would be nice, or perhaps have a boolean flag "includeLast:"

Comment: It will probably change 3 times before Swift 4.0.  The Swift 3.0 syntax for stride is returning to the way it was originally.

Comment: Yeah, and I'm okay with this, personally. They're doing a pretty good change of informing you what you need to change to. Hopefully they'll diverge on an even better language this way